# Decide whether the function $f(x,y)=\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2+\sin^2y}{x^2+y^2}$ has a limit at $(0,0)$.

Tags: calculus, limits

$$f(x,y) = \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2+\sin^2y}{x^2+y^2}$$

This is what I have so far:

The limit is equal to zero. Since $x^2\leq\ x^2+y^2$, we have $\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\leq 1$. Therefore,

$$0 \leq \left|\frac{x^2+\sin^2y}{x^2+y^2}\right| \leq |\sin^2y|$$

Not sure if this answer is enough?

Comment: I don't know about your case but the answer to these questions except in very contrived situations is DNE.

Comment: That is true that $\sin(y)^2 \leq y^2$, hence $f(x,y) \leq 1$. But this doesn't prove anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{x^{2}+\sin^{2}y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}-1\right|&=\left|\frac{\sin^{2}y-y^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right|\\
&=\left|\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{\sin^{2}y}{y^{2}}-1\right)y^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right|\\
&=\left|\dfrac{\sin^{2}y}{y^{2}}-1\right|\left|\dfrac{y^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right|\\
&\leq\left|\dfrac{\sin^{2}y}{y^{2}}-1\right|\\
&\rightarrow 0
\end{align*}
as $(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$.

Comment: So by Squeeze Theorem $\dfrac{x^{2}+\sin^{2}y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\rightarrow 1$.

Comment: Isn't that cheating? You are checking the definition of convergence to $1$, not actually computing the limit ;P

Comment: Actually $\sin^{2}y$ is almost identically to $y^{2}$ when $y$ small, if we substitute that, then it is clear the limit is $1$, that is some sense of computation.

Answer (score 0):

That limit can not be equal to zero. Send $y\to 0$ and you get $1$, whatever $x$ does...

You might want to try using that $$y-\frac{y^3}{6} \le sin(y)\le y\,.$$

Using that you easily find as upper bound to your limit $1$. Then passing to polar coordinates you get (after easy algebraic manipulations) a lower bound depending only on $\rho$ and you can conclude by squeeze theorem.

Computation follows. I am unable to put the whole thing in a spoiler box.

Your limit is $1$. As said you can estimate as follows
$$\frac{x^2+\sin^2(y)}{x^2+y^2} \ge \frac{x^2+y^2 -y^4/6 +y^6/36}{x^2+y^2} = 1 -\frac{y^4}{36}\frac{6-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$$ 
Pass to polar coordinates and you get
$$\ge 1- \frac{\rho^4\sin^4\theta}{36}\cdot\frac{6-\rho^2\sin^2\theta}
 {\rho^2} \ge 1- \frac{\rho^2}{36}(6+\rho^2)\to 1$$